# Can't get TOP and ORDER BY to work in my Statement

Tags: c#, ms-access, sql-order-by

I have to Display the Top-n Movies based on their # of reviews and list it in Descending order based on reviews and was able to come up with this so far:

```
string mySql = "SELECT Movies.MovieName, COUNT(Reviews.MovieID) AS 
NumberOfReviews FROM Reviews INNER JOIN Movies ON Movies.MovieID = 
Reviews.MovieID GROUP BY MovieName";
///Sets up the connection to the server 
OleDbConnection db = new OleDbConnection();
db.ConnectionString = FormMainMenu._DBConnectionInfo;
//open database
db.Open();
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(mySql, db);
//Creates a data set out of the data
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(mySql, db);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
//Fills the table
adapter.Fill(ds);
DataTable dt = ds.Tables["TABLE"];      //Creates a datatable of all the movies in the database

BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();
bindingSource.DataSource = dt;
dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource;
adapter.Update(ds);
//close the database
db.Close();
```

What i can't get working is where to put the *TOP* to only list say 5 or 10 etc in the DataTable and getting *ORDER BY* to work

Using an Access Database

Comment: Just use `SELECT TOP 5` or maybe `SELECT TOP 10`.  Have a look at the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for more information.

Comment: Are you really using Oracle?!?

Comment: I've switched your oracle tag to ms-access

Comment: I added the jet tag, but removed it again when I caught a comment that this was v12 - this is ACE/ACCDB, the successor to jet, and while it's claimed that it's backwards compatible the question isn't strictly about jet. Stackoverflow doesn't appear to have a tag for ACE/ACCDB and I haven't yet found anything that indicates it's acceptable to tag with JET for ACE questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below - it'll work in sql server

```
SELECT top 5 Movies.MovieName, COUNT(Reviews.MovieID) AS 
NumberOfReviews FROM Reviews INNER JOIN Movies ON Movies.MovieID = 
Reviews.MovieID GROUP BY MovieName
order by COUNT(Reviews.MovieID) desc
```

for oracle you can try below

```
 select * from 
(SELECT Movies.MovieName, COUNT(Reviews.MovieID) AS 
    NumberOfReviews FROM Reviews INNER JOIN Movies ON Movies.MovieID = 
    Reviews.MovieID GROUP BY MovieName
    order by COUNT(Reviews.MovieID) desc
) where rownum<=10
```

Comment: I'm getting an Error that says "The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect"

Comment: what is your dbms name?

Comment: Its connecting to an Access database file

Comment: And yet you put an "oracle" tag on your question.  As far as I know "SELECT TOP..." works with Access, but seriously there's no good reason to even use Access DBs this day and age.

Comment: It's sadly the only DB our professor gave us to work with for doing the project

Comment: So what happens if you try `SELECT TOP 5 MovieName` (etc.)?

Comment: From what I'm understanding, Access does not support using `TOP`

Comment: Your understanding is wrong. MS Access does support a TOP predicate.

Answer (score 0):

`Top` cannot be used for Oracle, then you may use `row_number` instead.

```
SELECT MovieName, NumberOfReviews
  FROM
  (
  SELECT MovieName, NumberOfReviews, 
         row_number() over (ORDER BY NumberOfReviews DESC) as rn
    FROM
    (
    SELECT m.MovieName, COUNT(r.MovieID) AS NumberOfReviews
      FROM Reviews r
     INNER JOIN Movies m
        ON m.MovieID = r.MovieID
     GROUP BY m.MovieName
    ) 
  )  
 WHERE rn <= 5;
```

For `DB` Version `12`, `fetch` clause might be used as :

```
SELECT m.MovieName, COUNT(r.MovieID) AS NumberOfReviews
  FROM Reviews r
 INNER JOIN Movies m
    ON m.MovieID = r.MovieID
 GROUP BY m.MovieName
 FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY;
```